# Git Clone throwing a fatal error

Tags: git

I am trying to clone a project using Bash & am getting this error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github. ...': Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8087: Connection refused
```

It works just fine on my personal laptop. Is it maybe a proxy issue as I am using company laptop (network)?

Comment: please show your full command line.

Comment: @Daniel
git clone https;//github. ..  the usual clone command

Comment: please paste that here exactly how you entered it.

Comment: @Daniel
git clone https://github.com/angular/angular.git

Comment: `git clone https://github.com/{owner}/{repo}.git` make sure this is the format you have.

Comment: or use the ssh form `git clone git@github.com:{owner}/{repo}.git`

Comment: What's {owner} and {repo}, just to be clear

Comment: when reading a github project page - such as https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-layout - the owner is "angular-ui" and the repo is "ui-layout"

Comment: @Daniel
Now I have a different error ..

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what was happening is, there is a file in C:\Users\ADMIN\ called .gitconfig
It was pointing to my local (127.0.0.1) rather than github.com.